# How to use SQL join with case

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm getting incorrect syntax here:

```
  SELECT  
         BA.Bank,
         BA.AccountNo, 
         BA.closingBalance, 
         BT.TransactionDate =(Case When ClosingBalance <= 0 Then Getdate()
                                   Else TransactionDate
                              End),
         BankaccountID
  FROM BankTransactionDetail BT Right Join dbo.BankAccount BA  ON 
       BT.AccountID = BA.AccountID
```

Getting error: Incorrect syntax near '='.

Note: without join its working fine. Plaese help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this

```
SELECT BK.BankCode, 
         BA.Bank,
         BA.AccountNo, 
         BA.closingBalance, 
         Case When BA.ClosingBalance <= 0 Then Getdate() Else BT.TransactionDate End,
         BankaccountID
FROM BankTransactionDetail BT Right Join dbo.BankAccount BA  ON BT.AccountID = BA.AccountID
```

*Or*

Try this

```
  SELECT BA.Bank,
         BA.AccountNo, 
         BA.closingBalance, 
         TransactionDate =(Case When ClosingBalance <= 0 Then Getdate() Else TransactionDate End),
         BankaccountID
  FROM BankTransactionDetail BT Right Join dbo.BankAccount BA  ON BT.AccountID = BA.AccountID
```

Answer (score 1):

While defining the alias column do not use table suffix. In your case, you are deriving the column **'TransactionDate'** and trying to prefix it with **BT**. The moment you prefix, SQL Server will try to read that column from the BT table and it thinks that you are assigning the derived column to existing column. Just remove the BT prefix , it should work for you.

```
 SELECT BK.BankCode, 
             BA.Bank,
             BA.AccountNo, 
             BA.closingBalance, 
             TransactionDate =(Case When ClosingBalance <= 0 Then Getdate()
                                       Else TransactionDate
                                  End),
             BankaccountID
      FROM BankTransactionDetail BT Right Join dbo.BankAccount BA  ON 
           BT.AccountID = BA.AccountID
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
SELECT  
     BA.Bank,
     BA.AccountNo, 
     BA.closingBalance, 
     (CASE WHEN ClosingBalance <= 0 THEN GETDATE()
           ELSE TransactionDate
           END) AS TransactionDate,
      BankaccountID
FROM  BankTransactionDetail BT Right Join dbo.BankAccount BA  ON 
      BT.AccountID = BA.AccountID
```